# Pine Script in TradingView - Change text color

Tags: pine-script

I make a color change like tutorial movie and it is workinggreat, but I cant add third step.
I want to change text color when oscillator is above 80 and below 20 now I have something like this :

```
color colorExtreme = input(color.rgb(232,32,97, 10), type=input.color)    
color colorNormal = input(color.rgb(255,255,255, 30), type=input.color)    
table.cell(ScanTab, 3, 1, MFI_M_show, bgcolor=color.rgb(178,180,191, 90), text_color=MFI_M >= 80 ? colorExtreme : colorNormal, text_size=size.small)
```

When I try add the parametr "and" i have error, how i can add third step to change color below 20
Thank you